# fio test tool's option runtime has no effect

Tags: docker, io, performance-testing, qemu

I run a docker container in my server, and then I run qemu in this container. Firstly, I don't open the option `enable-kvm` in qemu, and the fio `runtime` option works. I set `runtime=30` and the fio test last at most 30s. But when I open the option `enable-kvm`, the fio option `runtime=30` doesn't work. The fio process runs just a few seconds and then finished.

note that I don't use fio option `size`, so I think it should run 30s to finished.

How to fix this problem? Or if there other methods to make fio running 30s before it finish?

I just change the runtime option to `runtime=30s` and it doesn't work either.
the full command I use is

```bash
fio --filename=/dev/nullb0 --iodepth=64 --ioengine=psync --direct=1 --rw=randread --bs=$1k --numjobs=$2 --runtime=30s --group_reporting --name=test-rand-read --output=test_c_randwrite.log
```

My docker image is ubuntu22, and the qemu's kernel is `Rust for Linux`
My qemu command is

```bash
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -nographic --enable-kvm\
    -smp 4 -m 4096 \
    -kernel arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage \
    -append "console=ttyS0 root=/dev/sda rootfstype=ext4 rw" \
    -hda /data/bupt-rtos/x86_ramdisk/ubuntu-rootfs.img \
    -nic tap,id=net0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no\
    -object "filter-dump,id=net0,netdev=net0,file=dump.dat"
```

If you need more information, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that use the option `--time_based=1` can figure this problem. This works for me.